# The right .gitignore file for Symfony3

Tags: git, symfony

Using Symfony3, when a I do `git status` , I get

```
modified:   .gitignore
modified:   var/cache/dev/profiler/index.csv
modified:   var/logs/dev.log
```

I don't understand why because, this is my `.gitignore` file content:

```
/var/
!var/cache/.gitkeep
!var/logs/.gitkeep
/app/config/parameters.yml
/phpunit.xml
/vendor/
/web/bundles/
```

source: [Knp University](https://knpuniversity.com/screencast/symfony3-upgrade/new-dir-structure)

Comment: Also take a look at https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Symfony.gitignore

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a file once is tracked it will keep tracked. `.gitignore` just has effect on untracked files. You can not ignore changes to already tracked files. So if you want those files not tracked anymore, remove them from the repository in addition to adding them to `.gitignore`. If you want to keep the local copy use `git rm --cached`.

Comment: sorry I'm new with git (4 days ago) when I do: sudo git rm --cached var/  it does not work: fatal: not removing 'var/' recursively without -r

Comment: That would delete all files under `var` from your repository if you commit it. What does not work?

Comment: Well, the output tells you what is wrong. Add `-r` if you want to remove all files in a directory. Just the same is with standard file-system `rm`.

Comment: Fine of course I've done in that way but now when I do: sudo git status I get a stack of green message saying that the files have been removed how can I do to have a clean working environment like I just start a project with git ? sorry for I'm a newbie

Comment: Well, of course they are shown as removed, you just removed them, but you only added this removal to the so-called "index" for being included in the next commit. As soon as you commit, those files are removed from the repository

Comment: May the CREATOR of heaven and hearth bless you !

Answer (score 0):

is your question why it says that `var/cache/dev/profiler/index.csv` and `var/logs/dev.log` are marked as modified when they should be ignored by the first line in `.gitignore`?

Git only applies ignore patterns to untracked files. You can't ignore changes to files that git already track.

If you want to remove the files from the git repository, use `git rm`. To keep the local versions of the files, use `git rm --cached`.

If what you want to do is keep the files tracked, but also have a local version of the files that git shouldn't care about, see https://gist.github.com/canton7/1423106 for some possible workarounds.